# Background color for UITabBar and UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a ViewController embedded in a navigation controller which automatically creates a UINavigationBar. Then i've added a UITabBar to the bottom. How can i change the standard color of these.

i've tried this, but does not change the color:

```
UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed:248/255.0f green:243/255.0f blue:240/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
UIColor * navColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:176/255.0f green:189/255.0f blue:197/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = navColor;
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:color];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:navColor];
```

Comment: Is the navbar getting its colors set correctly?

Comment: For me this two works fine: `[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:color];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:navColor];` =)  I just setup the same as you and checked it=)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the appearance of controls with `UIAppearance` only takes effect the *next* time a control of that type is created. So if you're setting the appearance *after* creating your navigationBar and tabBar (which is probably the case if they're created in a storyboard), the appearance won't take effect.

Try calling your appearance code from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your AppDelegate (I'd recommend creating a `Themer` class which is responsible just for setting appearances - you could then create and use this from your AppDelegate), or otherwise set your navigationBar and tabBar appearance directly in your storyboard.

Comment: Here we are months later and this is helping me understand my issue before posting on here haha! Would love to see a bit more explanation to the themer class.